# Load jquery dynamically before using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My script will be using as widget in third-party website so i don't aware about jquery loaded and which version of jquery loaded or not at third-party end.

So Before loading  below script i want to check is there already latest jquery 1.11.1 loaded after dom ready if not then i want to load the jquery latest and run below script.

script.js

```
   var $ = jQuery.noConflict( true );
             (function( $ ) {
                   $(document).ready(function() {
                       alert("Document Ready ");
                     });
            })($jy);
```

### EDIT 1

```
var addNewJQuery = function() {
    (function( $ ) {
       $jy = $;
       var invokeOriginalScript;

      $(document).ready(function() {
            ......my code here.....
     }):
  })(jQuery);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is working for you, but it looks like it is working.

Maybe you need to remove the other script from your header after you loaded the second jQuery file. But it seems to work with both scripts loaded.

I've also added a check if jQuery is loaded at all, if not it will load jQuery.

You can also find the same code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/8j7teb79/).

```js
var addNewJQuery = function() {
    //var jQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("You are now running jQuery version: " + $.fn.jquery);
        });
    })(jQuery);
};

if ( typeof jQuery === 'undefined' ) {
    alert('no jQuery loaded');
    //throw new Error("Something went badly wrong!"); // now you could load jQuery
    loadScript('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js', addNewJQuery);
}

if ($.fn.jquery !== '1.11.2') {
    console.log('detected other jQuery version: ', $.fn.jquery);
    loadScript('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js', addNewJQuery);
}


function loadScript(url, callback)
{
    // Adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    // Then bind the event to the callback function.
    // There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;

    // Fire the loading
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i need to use var jQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);  because my widget also using other js library which use jQ that depends on jquery and if 3rd party webiste also using the same library then it creates a problem so i have used it and replcaced $jQ in other libraries

Comment: How can i use var jQ = jQuery.noConflict(true); with your given code?

Comment: What script do you want to run with the newly loaded jQuery? Can you please create a jsFiddle to show the problem?

Comment: It's difficult to read your page in the browser source code window. But I can't see that you've loaded requirejs in your page or have I missed it.